# How to apply js and css to ajax loaded content?

Tags: 8, theming, ajax

When content get loaded through ajax, neither theme.css or js get applied. Below is code snippet,

controller

```
    $twig = \Drupal::service('twig');
        $twigFilePath = drupal_get_path('module', 'mythemename') . '/templates/test.html.twig';
        $template =  $twig->loadTemplate($twigFilePath);
      $markup = $template->render(array('gainerList' => $gainerList, 'loseList' => $looserList));

        $build = array(
            '#type' => 'markup',
            '#markup' => $markup,
            '#attached' => array(
                'css' => array(
                    drupal_get_path('themes', 'mythemename') . '/css/theme.css'
                )
            )
        );
        return new Response(render($build));
```

Is there any issue with above code?

Also below testing code does not hide the second

.

```
 $build = array(
            '#type' => 'markup',
            '#markup' => '<p>Demo text content</p> <p style="display:none">Demo text content</p>',
        );
        return new Response(render($build));
```

Js file code snippet:

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
  'use strict';

  Drupal.behaviors.company = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
        $.ajax({
                url: "get-top-performing-fund",
                type: 'GET',
                success:function(data, error){
                    console.log(data);
                    $('#topPerforming').html();
                    $('#topPerforming').html(data);
                }
        });
    }
}
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any issue with above code?

Yes, you're using the D7 approach. In D8 it is different. You need to create a libraries.yml file where you will define your CSS and JS files.

See:

[Adding stylesheets (CSS) and JavaScript (JS) to a Drupal 8 module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module)

[Adding stylesheets (CSS) and JavaScript (JS) to a Drupal 8 theme](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme)

Once you have a library you can attach it like this:

```
  '#attached' => array(
    'library' => array(
      'your_theme/library_name',
    ),
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I already tried that, but its not working. Even I tired to attach library in template itself {{ attach_library('themename/global-styling') }} but weird its not working

Comment: @Sudha you need to be careful with your libraries.yml file. It is space sensitive. Wrong amount of spacing and it won't work. Also, clear all caches.

Comment: yup. my theme name is associates and library name is global-styling. So it becomes associates/global-styling but its still not working.  '#attached' => array(
    'library' => array(
      'associates/global-styling',
    )

Comment: isn't `global-styling` being already being loaded from your theme?

Comment: yes, but same does not work for ajax loaded content. :(

Comment: @Sudha post your JS file code. It's probably because you're not using `Drupal.behaviors`

Comment: updated my question

Comment: Is the libraries yaml you have even valid?

Comment: @kevin my libraries yml is getting included correctly on load of page by content loaded through ajax get display without any css and js.

Comment: @Sudha your JS has a line missing, you need to close it `})(jQuery, Drupal);`

Comment: Sorry I missed to post that in my question. Updated

Comment: @Sudha try using `alert('something');` instead of console log.

Comment: How can you say the library is being loaded if the files it lists are not? Have you linted the yaml file? Can you see the files loaded in the source?